# Getting Invalid Cast Exception from WpiApi?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I am trying to build a demo application using breeze and angular with WebApi. I am facing an exception while making a request to WebApi using breeze with .select('properties') method.

```
return EntityQuery.from('Sessions').select('id,title,code,speakerId,trackId,timeSlotId,roomId,level,tags').orderBy(orderBy).toType('Session').using(manager).execute().to$q(success, queryfailed);
```

> ExceptionMessage: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder+SelectSome`1[AngularBreezeSpa.Models.Session]]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[AngularBreezeSpa.Models.Session]'.",
>
> ExceptionType: "System.InvalidCastException",

but if i am not using **select()** then everything works fine. like below

```
return EntityQuery.from('Sessions').orderBy(orderBy).toType('Session').using(manager).execute().to$q(success, queryfailed);
```

Comment: I'm not using breeze, but, experiencing this precise error in my WebApi controller (was directly stolen from an MVC 4 / WebApi app, pasted into an MVC 5 / WebApi 2 app)

Answer (score 0):

### Updated 10/28/2013:

As of now, Breeze 1.4.5 has support for Microsoft's ASP.NET WebApi 2 and Entity Framework 6. Please see http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download.

### Old post...

This bug is because of Microsoft's changes to WebApi ( the new version is called WebApi 2) and Entity Framework ( EF5 -> EF6).

**We will be releasing Breeze support for both WebApi2 and Entity Framework 6 later this week.**

For now, its a bit painful, but you need to manually install the older ( v 4.x) versions of the "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.xxx" packages and the older Entity Framework v5 (not v6), before installing Breeze on VS 2013.